# Remove words in relation to size and not in other list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to delete words that have three letters but that do not belong to a list. I tried to do this:

```
text = 'je ne suis pas une table'
not_shortword = {'n', 'pas', 'ne'}
remove_shortword = ''.join(shortword for shortword in text if len(shortword) > 4 and shortword not in not_shortword)
```

My output:

> 'je e suis pas ue table'

Good output:

> ne suis pas table

Comment: Why is `"je"` not in the final output? Don't you want to delete _words whose `length == 3` and are `not in not_shortword` list_?

Comment: I messed up, I want to remove words that are less than 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to missing `split()` on `text`, you've got your conditions a little mixed up.
Try:

```
' '.join(
    shortword for shortword in text.split(" ") 
    if len(shortword) >= 3 or shortword in not_shortword
)
# 'ne suis pas table'
```

Answer (score 1):

The [split()](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split) in your case breaks in an array of element by the space (one element of array = one word). Looping through it it the solution

```
text = 'je ne suis pas une table'
not_shortword = {'n', 'pas', 'ne'}

rep = ' '.join(shortword  for shortword in text.split() if len(shortword ) >= 4 or shortword  in not_shortword)

print(rep)
#returns : "ne suis pas table"
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are splitting the text into a list of words with `.split()`:

```
remove_shortword = ' '.join(word for word in text.split() if len(word) >= 3 and word not in not_shortword)
```

Then join with a space instead of an empty string.

Comment: This code doesn't produce the desired result - the output here is just `'je une'`.

Comment: Returns `je une`